# Wrong Exception while connecting to MQTT server with an ActionListener (callback)

Tags: java, android, mqtt

This is my code:

```
 public void connect(Context application) throws MqttException {
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Connecting to MQTT");
    String mqttServerUri = "tcp://18.219.333.193:1883";
    String userName = "xxxxxxx";
    String password = "xxxxxxx";

    MqttAndroidClient client = new MqttAndroidClient(application, mqttServerUri, "mqtt-test");
    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    options.setCleanSession(false);
    options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
    options.setKeepAliveInterval(60 * 10);
    options.setMaxInflight(3000);
    options.setUserName(userName);
    options.setPassword(password.toCharArray());

    client.connect(options, iMqttActionListener);

}
```

here is the callback:

```
    final IMqttActionListener iMqttActionListener = new IMqttActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
        MqttHandler.isConnected.set(true);
        Log.d(TAG, "[MH] connected to mqtt server");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
        // Something went wrong e.g. connection timeout or firewall problems
        MqttHandler.isConnected.set(false);
        Log.e(TAG, "[MH] cannot connect to mqtt server", exception);
    }
};
```

But on executing the connect method, I get this exception:

```
[MH] cannot connect to mqtt server
Bad user name or password (4)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState.notifyReceivedAck(ClientState.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:145)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is the same exception which is thrown when user name or pass is actually wrong.

But when I replace this line:

```
client.connect(options, iMqttActionListener);
```

with this:

```
client.connect(options);
```

it works fine but I don't know when it has finished connecting, so its definitely not user/pass issue. But I do need the callback.

How can I fix this?

PS: 
I am using `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3` version: `1.2.0`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, just a flaw in API design.

If you check: org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient#connect(java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener)

```
@Override
public IMqttToken connect(Object userContext, IMqttActionListener callback)
        throws MqttException {
    return connect(new MqttConnectOptions(), userContext, callback);
}
```

The first argument is not a connection option, but a user context.

So, including callback, correct call would be:

```
client.connect(options, null, iMqttActionListener);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple.
`Eclipse Paho Client` library has several `connect()` method with callback.

You can refer to my answer in [MQTT Service Class Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598554/app-service-and-mqtt-crashes-when-wifi-disconnects-and-wont-reconnect)

I hope this helps you.